# Different options and pictures in Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm building a store with products that have multiple designs.  I'd like to have pictures for each design, and possibly be able to click on, or have a drop down menu that would change the picture when the design is chosen.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you would need to add a field where you could upload the product images and then use some javascript to listen to your modifier drop down changes. When the user changes the product variation you would need to then fire an event and find the corresponding image that you uploaded.